A way to make doc-view fit images by the width of the window automatically
So I have been using AUCTeX on Emacs recently, and I have been using doc-view to display the compiled pdf, but the doc-view standard resolution is too low and the image looks foggy, I increased the doc-view-resolution from 100 to 130 (not sure which units are these) and the results are way crispier, but in increasing the resolution the displayed image also increase. When searching about this, I found that I can run either doc-view-fit-width-to-window or doc-view-fit-height-to-window or doc-view-fit-page-to-window to make the image fit either with the window width or height or ... actually I don't know what this last one does exactly (does it deform the image so that it fills all of the window? Or does it scale the image to the maximum value for which the hole image is shown in the window?), but running these commands every time I compile a LaTeX file is a hassle, so I went to search for a way to do this automatically and found the following Stack Exchange post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236555/making-document-view-in-emacs-fit-to-width-of-page
In the first answer there appears to be a elisp code to make the doc-view buffer continuously adjust the image size to one of these choices, but this code does not seem to work for me, I initially tried the original code, it didn't work and I got a message that the cl package was deprecated, using another comment from that post I changed the (require 'cl) to (require 'cl-lib), this also does not work and now I get a message that 'lexical-let' is void, this also seems to be a depricated hack used before Emacs 24, but does this have to do with I needing to specify which of the three types of image resize would I want to be applied? And if so, where do I set this?

I highly recommend pdf-tools instead of doc-view.

I second @Tobias's recommendation. doc-view seems buggy to me: it does not itself define doc-view-mode-hook, although the mode does run it, but if I add-hook to it, opening the file the first time gives an error (as commented on in the link you provide). Be that as it may, you can still use W/H/P to run the various adjustment functions manually.

"not sure which units are these..." - they are DPI (dots per inch).
